# How to use a class decorator to implement the singleton pattern?

Tags: python, singleton, decorator

I want to use class decorator to implement the python singleton pattern.
I use two style of writing, but I do not get the same address of the class instance.

```
def singleton(cls):
    _instance = {}
    def _singleton(*args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in _instance:
            _instance[cls] = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        return _instance[cls]
    return _singleton

@singleton
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('A __init__')

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('B __init__')

a1 = A()
a2 = A()
print(id(a1), id(a2))
b1 = singleton(B)()
b2 = singleton(B)()
print(id(b1), id(b2))

A __init__
2777380227448 2777380227448
B __init__
B __init__
2777380227952 2777380237776
```

---

Two addresses of the class instance is not the same. I don't understand how it works. Aren't these just two ways of writing a class decorator?

Comment: With `B` you're calling `singleton` *twice*, so you have two "singletons". Try `B = singleton(B)`, that's the equivalent of decorating.

Comment: Your question is pretty good, however I suggest you improve your question,especially try to don’t add a picture, Have a look here => [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Just edit your question and add the output, this will also help users answer you question

Comment: i use the Single-step debugging，add the breakpoint  on the decorator function，i know the reason。